# How do I hide Mail Merge Row Results in MS Word?

Tags: vba, ms-word, mailmerge

I have a set of survey responses (scored 1-5) grouped by question. Right now I have the items being displayed with the respondent ID, the value of the response and a Sum at the bottom.

I would love to be able to hide the results row and just show the question and the average (while hiding all of the individual responses).

Here is how I have the Merge setup

```
«TableGroup:ReportData:Description:Show»

Fellow  Response
«TableStart:ReportData»«Responder_ID»
«Response»«TableEnd:ReportData»

Average 0.0
```

Sorry the table formatting was lost, but the Description is displayed on the top row, then you have 2 columns Fellow and Response. A single row which contains everything from the TableStart to the TableEnd and a row with the average.

The formula that is currently showing the 0.0 is:

```
=SUM(ABOVE)/COUNT(ABOVE)
```

My hope is to hide the information between TableStart and TableEnd so I can show a question and the average without the individual responses displaying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write something yourself using hidden text, or just use http://www.moreaddin.com/